# Report on Multiple Child Objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, reporting, joined-reports

Is it possible to create a report that combines multiple child objects into one report? Hopefully into a pie chart or doughnut. I can't find a way to do this in standard reporting, so I was wondering if this could be accomplished in visual force. I have found some documentation online, but they seem to be focusing on single object or hierarchies of objects.

Use case is I would like a report on Accounts that pulls tasks, events, and four or five custom objects into a single report.

Past that question, is it then possible to have the report filtered on a custom field on the Account object? I would like to run a report on several Accounts sharing the same value in a custom object.

Here are a few of the resources I have found:
[Focus on Force](http://focusonforce.com/visualforce/visualforce-reports/)
[Customize Report using VF/Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gyGyAAI)
[Using an iFrame](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008omGIAQ)

Comment: Yes, you can pull child records see here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003405&type=1 and this 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002591&type=1

It has limitation to 4 child object.

Comment: Thank you @AvijitChakraborty but this isn't what i am looking for. A joined report cannot be fully represented in a pie chart, correct? The values would have to be chosen among the different report types. For example, I would NOT be able to combine the account's activities with a custom object. Not only that, but this would not be filterable within Lightning if I were to add the report to the page.